# How to have two series in one chart in stimulsoft?

Tags: charts, regression, linear-regression, scatter, stimulsoft

[image]

I want to have a scatter diagram and its regression line simultaneously in one chart. How it is possible in stimulsoft ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a Scatter Line to the Scatter chart.